# Only display tweets from a single user using Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitterapi-python

I need to get the tweets from a single user in a streaming format. However, it still displays all tweets that retweet this user or are a reply to the tweets.

```
topic = "tweets"
accounts = ['user_id1', 'user_id2']

class TwitterStreamer():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def stream_tweets(self, topic, accounts):
        listener = StreamListener(topic)
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
        stream.filter(follow=accounts)


class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
        
    def __init__(self, file_prefix):
        self.prefix = file_prefix
    
    @property
    def fetched_tweets_filename(self):
        topic
        date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return f"{self.prefix}_{date}.txt"    
    
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
            
            with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
                tf.write(data)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
        return True
        
    def on_exception(self, exception):
        print('exception', exception)
        stream_tweets(topic, accounts)       

    def on_status(self, accounts, status):
        if status.user.id_str != accounts: 
            return
        print(status.text) 

def stream_tweets(topic, accounts):
    listener = StreamListener(topic)
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=accounts)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(topic, accounts)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I feel like the on_status command does not work at all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could it be that the returen result is a list? Also can't see any uses of the on_status method in the code.

Comment: Probably switch to v4.1.0? StreamListener has been merged into Stream since v4.0.0 (see changelog: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/changelog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the parameters for `on_status`. Your `accounts` variable is a global variable and you should use it as such. Also, `status.user.id_str` is a `str` but `accounts` is a `List[str]`. You need the `not ... in ...` operators as opposed to `!=`. In other words, try out the changes below:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    if not status.user.id_str in accounts: 
        return
    print(status.text)
```